# filter data having more than 1 record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  a table comprising departments;and the audit of persons added/removed from it.

```
deptid|personid|actionid|lastupdate
3|5678|i|....
3|5765|i|...
3|8796|i|...
3|5463|i|...
3|5678|r|.....
4|5678|i|....
```

In a particular department,I need to find out the audit for all those persons who have been actioned MORE THAN ONCE for a given department.

Note that a person can be allocated against multiple departments.

So in the above data,the result expected is:

```
3|5678|i|....
3|5678|r|.....
```

I tried the below - but do not know how to proceed to filter further

```
select personId,actionid,lastUpdate,RN=ROW_NUMBER()  
OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY lastUpdate)
from DeptAudit where deptId=3
```

Comment: but none of the person id is repeating in the data. unable to understand your prob exactly..

Comment: editted the post - there was a small typo

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can help:

```
SELECT personId,actionid,lastUpdate 
  FROM DeptAudit
 WHERE personid IN 
         (SELECT personId 
            FROM DeptAudit 
           GROUP BY personId 
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Widget  TABLE 
(ID INT,
Widget  INT,
PART NVARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @Widget VALUES 
(3, 56757, 'i'),
(3, 56755, 'i'),
(3, 56759, 'i'),
(3, 56753,'i'),
(3, 5678, 'r');


;WITH CTE AS (
select ID,Widget,PART,RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PART ORDER BY Widget desc) from @Widget
)select ID,Widget,PART from CTE WHERE RN = 1
```